# How to draw box containing string when using drawInRect?

Tags: iphone, string, draw, rect

I am using drawInRect from UIKit to draw a string. I want to also draw (see) the bounding rectangle where the string is drawn (sort of having a string inside a box). How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawInRect` UIKit methods return a `CGSize`, which is the size of the drawn string. Use this together with the origin of the `CGRect` you passed to `drawInRect`, and that is the rect you want to draw.

```
CGSize size = [string drawInRect:rect .... plus your options];
CGRect boundingRect = rect;
boundingRect.size = size;

[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:boundingRect] stroke];
```

Answer (score 0):

drawinRect does not return CGSize anymore, so based on jrturton's post, I used something like this to get a box drawn exactly around string contents -

```
[str1 drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

CGRect boundingRect = [str1 boundingRectWithSize:rect.size options:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping | NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:nil];
boundingRect.origin.x = rect.origin.x;
boundingRect.origin.y = rect.origin.y;

[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:boundingRect] stroke];
```